# Como encerrar um script com threads em Python

Tags: python, thread

Estou trabalhando com um projeto e preciso que o usuário tenha a opção de encerra-lo a qualquer momento, a maneira mais limpa de fazer isso que encontrei até agora foi pelo gerenciador de processos encerrando o processo python:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E isso me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por se tratar de algo que foi feito via gerenciador de tarefas eu creio que talvez exista algo que possa ser escrito no prompt de comandos via script para executar a mesma tarefa.

Ps: Eu fiz pesquisas e encontrei varias maneiras de encerrar um script porém, já tentei utilizar `exit()`, `sys.exit()` e `quit()` mas eles não encerram o código por completo pois meu código utiliza *Threading.*

Talvez o caminho que eu esteja seguindo não seja o melhor para a situação, então qualquer ajuda sobre como encerrar o código por completo será bem vinda.

Comment: Recomendo que edite a pergunta e insira o seu código. Se você mesmo suspeita que não está fazendo da melhor forma, precisamos ver o código para saber como fez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o código principal para ser o menu de sua aplicação e matar as threads quando necessário, como nesse simples exemplo (Python 3):

```
import threading
import time

def start():
    t1 = Thread()
    t1.start()
    op = 0
    while op != -1:
        print("Digite -1 para parar :)")
        op = int(input())
    print("saiu")
    t1.stop()

class Thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self.kill = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        # Enquanto a thread não estiver 'morta'
        while not self.kill.is_set():
            print("Thread executando")
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        # Mata a thread
        print("thread parando.")
        self.kill.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

A thread vai ser executada enquanto o atributo `self.kill` não estiver 'set', e você pode implementar uma função mais complexa no `stop()` para garantir que o encerramento da thread não cause nenhum problema (como em manipulação de dados, etc).

Comment: Augusto muito obrigado, eu não vou ter problemas com a manipulação de dados nesse script então o seu exemplo me atendeu perfeitamente